# Xamarin Android update the source (LoadUrl) of a webview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview

I'm using Xamarin Android and MVVMCross to develop my app. Within one of my views I have a webview element (amongst others). I use this element to embed a YouTube Video. If I hardcode the url like "https://www.youtube.com/embed/AAAAAAAA" this works fine.

view.xml:

```
...
 <android.webkit.WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
 />
...
```

view.cs:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.taskdetail_view);
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            var toolbarTitle = FindViewById<Android.Widget.TextView>(Resource.Id.toolbarTitle);
            toolbarTitle.Text = ViewModel.TaskName;

            var webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
            WebSettings settings = webView.Settings;
            settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webView.LoadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/AAAAAAAA");
        }
```

So far so good. Now I would like to inject the string for the LoadUrl method programmatically. Therefore, I created a service class that makes a webcall to the youtube data api in order to retreive a video id. After the api has returned a video id, a public property in the viewmodel gets updated with that id. All this works just fine, but how do I update the source of the webview? I thought of something like:

```
string videoURL = ViewModel.YoutubeVideoId;
 ...
webView.LoadUrl(videoURL);
```

But since the webview is configured in the OnCreate method of the view, the api call has not been made yet and the property on the viewmodel is still null.

So ultimately my goal would be to display the view, then start the api call in the background, when the call has finished update the source of the webview. The most convenient would be to use mvvmcross binding, but that doesn't seem to work out of the box. So how can I do this?

**UPDATE**

I got it to work by using a timer. In the OnCreate method in the view I use this code:

```
timer = new Timer
{
   Enabled = true,
   Interval = 500
};
timer.Elapsed += OnTimeEvent;
```

And then I declare the OnTimeEvent function:

```
private void OnTimeEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                if(ViewModel.YoutubeVideoId != "https://www.youtube.com/embed/")
                {
                    timer.Dispose();
                    string videoURL = ViewModel.YoutubeVideoId;
                    var webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
                    WebSettings settings = webView.Settings;
                    settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                    webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                    webView.LoadUrl(videoURL);
                    webView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

                    var progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
                    progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                }
            });
        }
```

Of course, using a timer is not the best solution. Is there a way to implement something like a callback that gets executed after ViewModel.YoutubeVideoId is updated?

Comment: if you want to use MvvmCross,you could refer to [Xamarin Android MvvmCross](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/890595/introduction-to-xamarin-android-with-mvvmcross/),and you also could define a interface,then implement it in your activity,update the url after reuqest api,or use broadcast receive to acheve it

Comment: Leo, thank you for the link. That is pretty much the pattern I use for my app. However, I cannot bind to the source property or LoadUrl method of webview.

Comment: you could consider using interface in your service which you request api to get the new url